# How to save an object through GGally in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I have a pretty dumb question to ask everyone.

I am using ggpairs under GGally to create a correlation matrix, and somehow I found that GGally did not provide a saving function as ggplot2 did. The function ggsave did not work for a non-ggplot2 object. I tried to use pdf or png, but they did not work. I am wondering if there's an easy to save this picture to a local file? Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Could you use getPlot to retrieve the ggplot object and then use ggsave on this object?

Comment: Something similar to: `graph <- ggplot...` then `ggsave("mygraph.png", graph, width = 6, height = 6)`

Comment: @KFB But ggsave does not recognize an object that is not a ggplot2 object. I tried to use this but it's not working.

Comment: Reiterating my comment: `getPlot` from GGally returns the ggplot object.

Comment: thank you for this question. I am a ggplot native and, while I once used base plotting, it's been a while, and for better or worse, I often tend to google before trying things.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While @CMichael's comment is nice (I didn't know that, hence +1), it's applicable only if you want to save a *particular plot* from GGally-generated plot matrix. I believe that you'd like to save the **whole plot matrix** - the need, which I've recently also experienced. Therefore, you can use a standard R approach and save the graphics by opening corresponding (to desired format) graphical device, printing the object and closing the device, which will effectively save the graphics in a desired format.

```
# use pdf() instead of svg(), if you want PDF output
svg("myPlotMatrix.svg", height = 7, width = 7)
g <- ggpairs(...)
print(g)
dev.off()
```

Comment: This works! Actually the method provided by @CMichael works also, but could only retrieve part of the plot. While if you want to save the whole matrix, this is the solution to go.